# Need to convert from ISpatialReference to SpatialReference

Tags: arcobjects, c#, coordinate-system

I am attempting to write a method in C# that will accept as input, an ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReference object and convert it to an ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference object.  I need this for converting an IPoint to a MapPoint.  Are there any online resources for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the factory code from the ISpatialReference object to create a new spatial ref. If your client geometry obj was named myGeom and input spatial ref was named inputSR then it would look something like this:

```
myGeom.SpatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(inputSR.FactoryCode);
```